# How do I block videos by keyword on YouTube using squid?

Tags: proxy, youtube, squid

I  installed squid 2.7 + squidguard in windows 7.  How do I block videos by keyword on YouTube using Squid?

For example, I want to block videos that contain the word **cats** in the title. I also do not want the blocked videos appearing in:

- Recommended Channels tab
- Recommended/related videos
- Search results

As shown in image:

[image: pic]

Comment: Sorry, meant to write "cats"

Comment: @Linger : Thank you for improving the format.

Comment: It's just an example.It should work like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-blocker/jknkjnpcbbgcbdbaampbjlhkcghmgfhk/details?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)  (sorry, english is not my first language)

Comment: @Scott I edited the image,is it OK now?

Comment: @Scott Another example: [link](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/156278.html) ,the problem is i have to block each video that i hate manually.